# Is there an official list of Shaktipeeths?

Tags: shiva, devi, shiva-purana, shakti, sati-goddess

Is there an official list of Shaktipeeths? If yes, please provide the list and source.

Comment: You can have a look at [Sati’s body being cut into pieces by the Chakra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15937/20129)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official list of Śākta Pīṭhas is found in the Pīṭhanirṇaya. Sāktas consider it the most important text regarding the Śākta Pīṭhas. This text is also known as Mahāpīṭhanirūpaṇa. Fifty-one Pīṭhas are mentioned in that text along with other details like the name of the Bhairava etc. Here it is presented in the tabulated form.

---

| No. | Pitha | Location* | Anga | Devi | Bhairava |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hiṅgulā | Hinglaj, Pakistan | Brahmarandhra | Koṭṭarī | Bhīmalocona |
| 2 | Karavirā | Maharashtra, India | Trinetra | Mahiṣamardinī | Krodhīśa |
| 3 | Sugandhā | Shri Sugandha Devi Mandir, Barishal, Bangladesh | Nāsikā | Sunandā | Tryambaka |
| 4 | Kāśmīra | Sarada Peeth, Pak Occupied Kashmir, India | Kaṇṭha | Mahāmāyā | Trisandhyeśvara |
| 5 | Jvālāmukhī | Himachal Pradesh, India | Jihvā | Siddhidā | Unmatta |
| 6 | Jālandhara | Pujab, India | Stana | Tripuramālinī | Bhīṣaṇa |
| 7 | Vaidyanātha | Jharkhand, India | Hṛdaya | Jayadurgā | Vaidyanātha |
| 8 | Nepāla | Guhyeshwari Shaktipeeth (near Pashupatinath), Nepal | Jānu | Mahāmāyā | Kapālī |
| 9 | Mānasa | Kailas-Manas Sarobar, Tibet, China | Dakṣina-hasta | Dākṣāyaṇī | Hara |
| 10 | Virajākṣetra | Puri, Odisha, India | Nābhi | Vimalā | Jagannātha |
| 11 | Gaṇḍakī | Shree Muktinath Temple, Nepal | Gaṇḍa | Gaṇḍakī | Cakrapāni |
| 12 | Bāhulā | Ketugram, Burdwan, West Bengal, India | Vāma-bāhu | Bahulā | Bhīruka |
| 13 | Ujanī | Mangalkote, Burdwan, West Bengal, India | Kūrpara | Maṅgalācaṇḍī | Kapileśvara |
| 14 | Caṭṭala | Chandranath temple, Chittagong, Bangladesh | Dakṣiṇa-bāhu | Bhavānī | Candraśekhara |
| 15 | Tripurā | Tripura, India | Dakṣiṇa-pāda | Tripurasundarī | Tripureśa |
| 16 | Trisrotā | Trisrota Maa Bhramari Shakti peeth, Jalpaiguri, West Bengal, India | Vāma-pāda | Bhrāmarī | Iśvara |
| 17 | Kāmagiri | Kāmarūpa, Assam, India | Yoni | Kāmākhyā | Umānanda |
| 18 | Yugādyā | Jogadya temple, Khirgram, Mangolkote, Burdwan, West Bengal, India | Dakṣina-pādāṅguṣṭha | Yugādyā | Kṣīrakhaṇḍa |
| 19 | Kālīpīṭha | Kalighat, Kolkata, West Bengal, India | Dakṣiṇa-pādāṅguli | Kālī | Nakuleśa |
| 20 | Prayāga | Uttar Pradesh, India | Hast-āṅguli | Lalitā | Bhava |
| 21 | Jayantī | Meghalaya, India | Vāma-jaṅghā | Jayantī | Kramadīśvara |
| 22 | Kirīṭa or Kirīṭakoṇā | Kiriteshwari Shaktipeeth, West Bengal, India | Kirīṭā | Bhuvaneśī | Siddhirūpa |
| 23 | Maṇikarṇikā | Varanasi, Uttara Pradesh, India | Kuṇḍala | Viśālākṣī | Kāla |
| 24 | Kanyāśrama | Kanyakumari, Tamilnadu, India | Pṛṣṭha | Sarvāṇī | Nimiṣa |
| 25 | Kurukṣetra | Shri Devikoop Bhadrakali Shaktipeeth, Haryana, India | Dakṣiṇa-gulpha | Sāvitrī | Sthāṇu |
| 26 | Maṇiveda | Gayatri Shakti Peeth (near Pushkar), Rajasthan | Maṇibandha | Gāyatrī | Sarvānanda |
| 27 | Śriśaila | ShriShri Mahalakshmi Bhairabi Griba Shaktipeeth, Sylhet, Bangladesh | Grīvā | Mahālakṣmī | Saṃvarānanda |
| 28 | Kāñcī | Kankalitala Mandir, Birbhum, West Bengal, India | Kaṅkāla | Devagarbhā | Ruru |
| 29 | Kālamādhava | Near Amarkantak, Madhya Pradesh, India | Nitamba | Kālī | Asitāṅga |
| 30 | Narmadā | Near Kalmadhav, Madhya Pradesh, India | Nitamba | Śoṇā | Bhadrasena |
| 31 | Rāmagiri | Chitrakoot, Madhya Pradesh, India | Stana | Śivānī | Caṇḍa |
| 32 | Vṛndāvana | Uttar Pradesh, India | Keśa | Umā | Bhūteśa |
| 33 | Śuci | Tamilnadu, India | Ūrdhva-danta | Nārāyaṇī | Saṃhāra |
| 34 | Pañcasāgara | Maa Varahi Shakti Peeth, Uttar Pradesh, India | Adho-danta | Vārāhī | Mahārudra |
| 35 | Karatoyātaṭa | Shri Shri Aparna Shakti Peeth, Bhawanipur, Rajshahi, Bangladesh | Vāma-karṇa | Aparṇā | Vāmana |
| 36 | Śrīparvata | Srisailam, Andhra Pradesh, India | Dakṣiṇa-karṇa | Sundarī | Sundarānanda |
| 37 | Vibhāsa | Kapalini Bhimarupa Shakti Peeth, Tamluk, Medinipur, West Bengal, India | Vāma-gulpha | Bhīmarūpā | Kapālī |
| 38 | Prabhāsa | Shri Chandrabhaga Shaktipeeth, near Somnath, Gujrat, India | Udara | Candrabhāgā | Vakratuṇḍa |
| 39 | Bhairavaparvata | Ujjain, Madhya Pradesh, India | Ūrdhv-oṣṭha | Avantī | Lambakarṇa |
| 40 | Janasthāna | Nashik, Maharashtra, India | Civuka | Bhrāmarī | Vikṛta |
| 41 | Godāvarītīra | Kotilingala, Andhra Pradesh, India | Vāma-gaṇḍa | Viśveśi | Viśveśa |
| 42 | Ratnāvalī | Khanakul, Hooghly, West Bengal, India | Dakṣiṇa-skandha | Kumārī | Śiva |
| 43 | Mithilā | Mithila Shakti Peeth, Bahadurpur, near Dwarbhanga, Bihar, India | Vāma-skandha | Umā | Mahodara |
| 44 | Nalāhāṭī | Birbhum,West Bengal, India | Nalā | Kālī | Yogīśa |
| 45 | Kālīghāṭa | Shri Chamundeswari Temple, Mysuru, Karnataka, India | Muṇḍa | Jayadurgā | Krodhiśa |
| 46 | Vakreśvara | Birbhum, West Bengal, India | Manas | Mahiṣamardinī | Vakranātha |
| 47 | Yaśora | Jessoreshwari temple,Jessore,Khulna, Bangladesh | Pāṇi | Yaśoreśvarī | Caṇḍa |
| 48 | Aṭṭahāsa | Burdwan, West Bengal, India | Oṣṭha | Phullarā | Viśveśa |
| 49 | Nandipura | Nandikeshwari temple, Saithia, Birbhum, West Bengal, India | Hāra | Nandinī | Nandikeśvara |
| 50 | Laṅkā | Shri Thirukoneswaram Kovil, Trincomalee, Srilanka | Nūpura | Indrākṣī | Rākṣaseśvara |
| 51 | Virāṭa | Shri Ambika Shaktipeeth, Rajasthan, India | Padāṅguli | Ambikā | Amṛta |

---

*Locations are added by me using the sources mentioned below. In a few cases, alternate views are there regarding locations.

**Reference -**

- The Śākta Pīṭhas by Dr D. C. Sirkar, published by Motilal
  Banarsidass. (Includes the Pīṭhanirṇaya text)
- Mahatirtha Ekanno Pither Sandhane [In search of fifty-one Peethas] by Nighudananda (Bengali)

Locations of 51 Sakta Pithas -
[image]

A zoomed in view of Sakta Pithas in Eastern India
[image]

Comment: Nice effort.  +10 :) Kudos for compiling it into a neat n clean table! Also, Is this work _Pīṭhanirṇaya_  separately found online? Perhaps in archives or else? Or is the book you cite _The Śākta Pīṭhas by Dr. D. C. Sirkar_  - is it available for free on the online platform?

Comment: @Vivikta Thanks. I think you can get it in the Internet archive.

Comment: @Vivikta Long back, I created a google earth file showing the locations of all the Saktapithas. I just added a couple of snapshots from that. But, it looks far better on the google earth interactive map. But, unfortunately, that cannot be embedded here.

Comment: @Vivikta If you want to know a bit more about the ancient four Pithas among these 51 Pithas, you can check out my answer to the following question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45144/what-are-the-famous-catus-peethas-according-to-the-early-tantra-and-sakta-tradit

Comment: Do know why The temple of rajrappa is not in the list. I used to live there and it is called a shakti peeth .

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow There are many temples which are called shakti peethas. Because at the later time there was an attempt by Shaktas to increase their sphere of influence by increasing the number of peethas. 108 shakti peethas were mentioned in some later secondary text, which at the end of the day did not get overall acceptance. This temple could be one of them. There are many peethas which are known as Upapeethas. 51 is the authoritative number of Maha peethas.

Comment: However according to tantriks the temple is at the level of Devi Kamakhya temple

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Local tantriks can claim. But there is no textual evidence that this temple or in fact any temple or peethas is at the level of Kamakhya Peetha. Kamakhya is one of the Adi Peethas of shaktism. It is one of the famous Catuspeethas. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45144/what-are-the-famous-catus-peethas-according-to-the-early-tantra-and-sakta-tradit/45150#45150

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there isn't any official list of Shaktipeeth. Since due to kalpabhed, the few of them changes.
Because, in the Sarasvata kalpa the deh of Sati is been cut into 108 parts thus 108 Shaktipeeth are mentioned per Devi Bhagwatam,7th Shaknda, 30th chapter,

> Vyas said, "O Janamejaya! Thus I have mentioned to you the one hundred and eight pīthas (sacred places or seats of the Deity) and as many Devīs. Thus are mentioned all the seats of the Devīs and along with that, the chief places in India (the world). He who hears these excellent one hundred and eight names of the Devī as well as Her seats, gets himself freed from all sins and goes to the Loka of the Devī."

As per Peethnirnaya it's 51,the verse found is as follows, Ishwar says,

> पञ्चाशदेकपीठानि एवं भैरवदेवताः ।
> अङ्गप्रत्यङ्गपातेन विष्णुचक्रक्षतेन च
> ममाद्यवपुषो देव हिताय त्वयि कथ्यते ॥३॥
> The Fifty One Shakti Peethas along with the Bhairava Devatas, created by falling of Body parts, being cut by the Chakra (Discus) of Vishnu, My Wonderful beginning (i.e. initial cause of manifestation in Shakti Peethas), is being spoken to you for the welfare of the Devas.

As per Shankara Samhita of Skanda Puran the list has 19 Shaktipeeths mentioned.
Tantrachudamani states 68.
And none of them is wrong, Since all these Purans r from different kalpas thus numbers too differ.

Some other sources to refer are, Shiva Purana, the Kalika Purana, the AshtaShakti.

But the Chatur MahaShaktipeeth are indeed same in all Kalpas.

कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Visit [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn more and edit by adding authentic sources.